# Проверка статуса платежа

Tags: python, django, requests

У меня есть функция, которая вызывается по нажатию кнопки **обновить**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
def check_payment_status(request, payment_id):
    ticket = WalletTicket.objects.get(payment_id=payment_id, payment_status='waiting')

    try:
        url = f"https://api.nowpayments.io/v1/payment/{payment_id}"
    except ConnectionError:
        redirect('money:wallet')

    payload={}
    headers = {
        'x-api-key': API_KEY
    }

    json_response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    response = json.loads(json_response.text)

    if response['payment_status'] == 'finished':
        ticket.payment_status = 'finished'
        user = User.objects.get(ticket.user)
        user.balance += int(response['pay_amount'])
        user.save()

        return redirect('money:wallet')
```

Насколько это правильно? Можно ли сделать это более удобней? итерироватся по всем платежным тикетам займет время, а каждый раз нажимать **обновить** не совсем удобно.

Comment: использовать для обновления ajax не?

Comment: посмотри в стороны фоновых задач, например celery

Comment: Засунуть отображаемое содержимое в frame, а условие функции в while, и отображать пользователю симпатишный preloader пока не выполнится условие функции

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятна постановка вопроса, но все же постараюсь на него ответить в пределах своих сил.

Я могу предложить вам следующий инфраструктурный вариант обработки данного сценария: На Front-end'е при загрузке страницы и после получения информации о всех платежах проверять список отображаемых платежей и выделять из них те, которые имеют статус "ожидает", затем, можно сделать асинхронную обработку статусов этих платежей, чтобы запросы к вашему API не замедляли "лицо" сайта.

Псевдокод:

```js
// Псевдофункция получающая массив из всех платежей пользователя
async function fetchAllInvoices() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(fetch("Endpoint Получения всех платежей"))
  });
}

// Псевдофункция получения одного платежа по id
async function fetchInvoiceById(id) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(fetch("Endpoint Получения одного платежа/" + id))
  });
}



// Псевдофункция цикла проверки "ожидающих платежей"
// Дизайн абсолютно не prod-ready, это просто вариант как можно задизайнить
// Думаю, причины почему это плохой код - очевидны, он будет крайне негибким
// и используется только ради иллюстрации идеи.
async function waitingCheckLoop() {
  var waiting_ids = []

  // Получение всех ожидающих платежей из всех платежей
  const ids = await fetchAllInvoices()
  forEach((id, ids) => {
    if (id.status == "waiting") {
      waiting_ids.push(id)
    }
  })

  // Конкурентно обрабатываем список всех интересующих id
  while (waiting_ids.length > 0) {
    // Ставим задержку на каждый вызов цикла проверки платежей + конкурентность
    setTimeout(() =>
      // Итерируемся по всем ожидающим платежам
      forEach((id, waiting_ids) => {
        // В данном случае конкурентность обязательна, иначе мы будем блокирующе
        // обрабатывать каждый платеж, а это долго.
        setTimeout(() =>  {
          var invoice = await fetchInvoiceById(id.id)
          // Если статус платежа изменился, мы убираем его со списка и обновляем
          // DOM*
          if (invoice.status != "waiting") {
            // Способ с фильтром мне не очень нравится, но, не будем изобретать слона
            waiting_ids = waiting_ids.filter(i => i.id != id.id)
            // * Здесь же я бы обновлял DOM, но я не уверен в идеоматичности таких
            // действий, так что просто оставлю этот комментарий здесь
          }
        }, 0)
      },
      5000 // 5 секунд
    )
  }
}

//...
// Какой-то некий механизм, создали платеж или что-то еще (Ваша бизнес логика мне не известна)
// Предположим, пусть эта функция будет коллбеком on-click для некой, единой "кнопки"
function sampleTrigger() {
  // Мажорная issue псевдокода, нет защиты от дурака. Если несколько раз вызвать функцию, несколько раз запуститься цикл проверки. Будьте внимательны
  waitingCheckLoop() // не используем await чтобы все начало вертеться в фоне
}
```

В нем я постарался передать идею которую хочу донести. Вы имеете возможность конкурентно (к сожалению, не очень лениво, из-за отсутсвия вебхуков в API платежного сервиса которое вы используете) обработать поток из платежей и аккуратно подождать их завершения.

Надеюсь, я смог как-то помочь вам приблизиться к решению вашей проблемы.
Если вы используете шаблонизацию на бекенде, а не какое-то клиентское решение, то я не думаю что вам составит труда перенести идею изложенную мной в серверный код шаблонизации.

Спасибо.

Comment: P.S. Не являюсь фронт разработчиком и мог наделать ошибок в псевдокоде на JS. Отнесусь с пониманием если их отметите, я их несомненно исправлю.